# terminating input in cmd

Tags: windows, command-prompt, flex-lexer

I am running flex on windows. After compiling lex.yy.c C code file I am getting an executable "a.exe" but after running that executable I don't know how to terminate my input in command prompt. I have tried ctrl+z but it doesn't seem to work. 
Instead ^z gets displayed.

In linux you terminate your input by pressing ctrl+d to see the output. I want to know the equivalent buttons in windows.

Answer (score 1):

This question has lain unanswered for some months, but the answer is simple.
It is not related to flex, but just how an end-of-file is entered in windows command-prompt.

<kbd>cntrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> is correct, but it works differently than the <kbd>cntrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> in linux. In linux when you type <kbd>cntrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> the input is terminated immediately, but in windows it does not. You still have to follow the <kbd>cntrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> by an enter key as it still reads whole lines. Once it has read the line with the <kbd>cntrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> it recognised the end-of-file. It also, as you noted, echoes `^Z` to the display.